# getting error Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays using nuralnet

Tags: neural-network, r

I have a data frame

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   2354 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ SessionID      : int  11 12 21 21 22 26 33 33 33 46 ...
 $ ItemID         : int  214821371 214717867 214548744 214838503 214837487 214714790 214706441 214820225 214834865 214716932 ...
 $ n              : int  2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ diffinscnd     : num  6.68 0 0.053 0.053 0 ...
 $ total_clicks   : int  2 1 2 2 1 1 6 6 6 4 ...
 $ unique_Category: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ unique_items   : int  1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Class          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mean.Class.    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ avg            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Category       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

when i am trying to apply neural network in using the code below

```
> set.seed(123)
>  smp_size <- floor(0.80 * nrow(dataset))
>   train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), size = smp_size)
>   trainset <- dataset[train_ind, ]
>  testset <- dataset[-train_ind, ]
> maxs <- apply(dataset, 2, max) 
>  mins <- apply(dataset, 2, min)
> scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(dataset, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
>   trainNN = scaled[train_ind , ]
>  testNN = scaled[-train_ind , ]
> creditnet <- neuralnet(Category ~ SessionID + ItemID + n + diffinscnd + total_clicks + unique_Category + unique_items + Class + avg, trainNN,hidden = 3, lifesign = "minimal",linear.output = FALSE, threshold = 0.1)
```

then i got the following error

hidden: 3    thresh: 0.1    rep: 1/1    steps: Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(1, act.temp) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
how to solve this error??